# Javascript Image placement in Puzzle Game

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get images to be called into a table for a Puzzle Game, but it's not doing anything.

My root folder has an index.html and a folder with the images in named "images"
My my images are named **P1.png** through to **P16.png**.

If you look at the how the game is suppose to work you will see that the table has
letters "A" to "O" and if you click on it, it moves it to the open space. I am trying to get the same result but with images instead of the letters.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Here is the code I am working on.**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Puzzle Game</title>
</head>

<body>
<center>
<form name=table>


<table border=1 cellpadding=1 cellspacing=1>
<tr>
<td colspan=4 align=center>GG WP</td>
</tr>

<script>
bx=3;
by=3;

for (y=0;y<4;y++) {
    document.write('<tr>');

for (x=0;x<4;x++) {
    document.write('<td><img onclick="move('+x+','+y+');"></td>');
}

document.write('</tr>');
}

function move(x,y) {
    ax=Math.abs(bx-x);
    ay=Math.abs(by-y);
    if (((ax*ay)==0)&&((ax+ay)==1)) {
        f=document.table;

        f.elements[4*by+bx].src=f.elements[4*y+x].src;
        f.elements[4*y+x].src="images/";

        bx=x; 
        by=y; 
        f.msg.value++;
   }
}
function rndize() {

    alpha="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO ";

    for (i=0;i<16;i++) {
        x=0;
        y=0;

        while (document.table.elements[4*y+x].src!="") {
            x=Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
            y=Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
        }

        document.table.elements[4*y+x].src="P"+i+".png";
    }

    bx=x;
    by=y;
}

rndize();

</script>

</table>
<table border=1 cellpadding=1 cellspacing=1>
</table>
</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

**Here is the is how the game is suppose to work.**

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Puzzle Game</title>
</head>

<body>
<center>
<form name=table>


<table border=1 cellpadding=1 cellspacing=1>
<tr>
<td colspan=4 align=center>GG WP</td>
</tr>

<script>





bx=3;
by=3;

for (y=0;y<4;y++) {
    document.write('<tr>');

for (x=0;x<4;x++) {
    document.write('<td><tt><input type=button value="   " ');
    document.write('onclick="move('+x+','+y+');"></tt></td>');
}

document.write('</tr>');
}

function move(x,y) {
    ax=Math.abs(bx-x);
    ay=Math.abs(by-y);

    if (((ax*ay)==0)&&((ax+ay)==1)) {
        f=document.table;

        f.elements[4*by+bx].value=f.elements[4*y+x].value;
        f.elements[4*y+x].value="   ";

        bx=x; 
        by=y; 
        f.msg.value++;
   }
}

function rndize() {

    alpha="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO ";

    for (i=0;i<16;i++) {
        x=0;
        y=0;

        while (document.table.elements[4*y+x].value!="   ") {
            x=Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
            y=Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
        }

        document.table.elements[4*y+x].value=alpha.substring(i,i+1);
    }

    bx=x;
    by=y;

}

rndize();




</script>
</table>
<table border=1 cellpadding=1 cellspacing=1>
</table>
</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't get what the problem is...

Comment: It's not loading the images into the table - the table stays empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `document.table.elements` contains elements of `<form name=table>`, which are `input button` elements but are not `img` elements.

It can be fixed like this:

```
<form name=table>


<table border=1 cellpadding=1 cellspacing=1>
<tr>
<td colspan=4 align=center>GG WP</td>
</tr>

<script>
bx=3;
by=3;

for (y=0;y<4;y++) {
    document.write('<tr>');

for (x=0;x<4;x++) {
    document.write('<td><img onclick="move('+x+','+y+');"></td>');
}

document.write('</tr>');
}

function move(x,y) {
    ax=Math.abs(bx-x);
    ay=Math.abs(by-y);
    if (((ax*ay)==0)&&((ax+ay)==1)) {
        f= document.table;
        var imgElements = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

        imgElements[4*by+bx].src = imgElements[4*y+x].src;
        imgElements[4*y+x].removeAttribute("src");

        bx=x; 
        by=y; 
        f.msg.value++;
   }
}
function rndize() {

    alpha="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO ";
    var imgElements = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

    for (i=0;i<16;i++) {
        x=0;
        y=0;

        while (imgElements[4*y+x].src!="") {
            x=Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
            y=Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
        }
        if (i < 15) {
            imgElements[4*y+x].src= "images/P"+i+".png";
        }

    }

    bx=x;
    by=y;
}

rndize();

</script>

</table>
<table border=1 cellpadding=1 cellspacing=1>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. The only problem now is that the onclick isn't working... When I click the image it is suppose to move it to the negative space.